# How can I work with the Tag property of a winforms checked listbox item?

Tags: winforms, tags, checkedlistbox, valuemember

How can I write a C# winforms code like this?

CheckedListBox items don't have 'Tag' and 'ValueMember' properties.

I know there are many alternatives to this. But I need to work it this way.

```
private void LoadPermissionsToCheckedListBox()
{
    Role selectedRole = (Role)comboBox1.SelectedItem;

    int i = 0;
    foreach (Permission p in selectedRole.PermissionItems)
    {
        checkedListBox1.Items.Add(p);
        checkedListBox1.Items[i].Tag = p;
    }

    checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "PermissionKey";
    checkedListBox1.ValueMember = "PermissionID";
}
```

Comment: Why are the many alternatives not feasible? What are your exact constraints here?

Comment: I just can't understand why the checkedlistbox control is developed using a different idea than that of ComboBox and ListBox control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no Tag property, but the CheckedListBox accepts any object (you don't have to put just strings in it). You can create your custom class to hold your data:

```
public class CheckListBoxItem
{
    public Permission Tag;
    public string Text;
    public override string ToString() { return Text; }
}
```

and then add this object as item

```
foreach (Permission p in selectedRole.PermissionItems)
{
    checkedListBox1.Items.Add(new CheckListBoxItem()
    {
        Tag = p,
        Text = p.PermissionKey
    });
}
```

Check:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/csharpgeneral/thread/80f29165-acb3-421f-b5bb-856ba99da703